# Getting this error after upgrading modules via Magento downloader

Tags: magento

```
   a:5:{i:0;s:243:"Error in file: "/home4/mastersl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.0.9-1.6.0.0.10.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'mgn_catalog_product_entity_group_price' already exists";i:1;s:1004:"#0 /home4/mastersl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /home4/mastersl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.6.0.0.9', '1.6.0.0.19')
#2 /home4/mastersl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.6.0.0.9', '1.6.0.0.19')
#3 /home4/mastersl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /home4/mastersl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /home4/mastersl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /home4/mastersl/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home4/mastersl/public_html/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:19:"/stairs/stairtreads";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the table `mgn_catalog_product_entity_group_price` in PhpMyAdmin (or whatever database tool you have available) and see if the structure matches this:

```
+-------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| value_id          | int(11)              | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| entity_id         | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| all_groups        | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| customer_group_id | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| value             | decimal(12,4)        | NO   |     | 0.0000  |                |
| website_id        | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

If it does then the script `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.0.9-1.6.0.0.10.php` doesn't need to run and it can be skipped.  Enter this query to get past the error.

```
UPDATE `mgn_core_resource`
SET `version` = '1.6.0.0.10'
WHERE `code` = 'catalog_setup';
```

Comment: Thanks,
It seems now I have encountered a new error, but with mgn_report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily.

Comment: I know of no easy way to do this.  You will have to check each module that throws an error against the `mgn_core_resource` table, and update the version number as appropriate.  The last time I had to fix a site with this problem I spent a whole day on it.  The out-of-sync problem can be caused by the upgrade getting interrupted by PHP timing out, that is why the `.htaccess` file usually has a very large `max_execution_time` limit.